# How to set feature options for cargo build?

Tags: rust, clion, rust-cargo

I use this kind of things:

```
#[cfg(feature = "myfeature")]
```

When I click "Build - Build Project" it calls `cargo build`. How can I specify that I want `myfeature` to be used? I found that I can specify it for my Run configuration but still it doesn't work for "Build".

Comment: In the Cargo book under the "cargo add" chapter, you can find how to add dependencies options: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-add.html#dependency-options

Answer (score 1):

On the command line, you'd use `cargo build --features myfeature`. In clion using the IntelliJ Rust plugin, you should be able to open the `Cargo.toml` file and tick the box next to the feature definition to enable it within the IDE, as demonstrated [in this blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2020/10/intellij-rust-new-functionality-for-cargo-features/).

Comment: It works within IDE code highlighting but when I "Build" it still doesn't pass the ticked features.